# Imagebutton inside a fragment clicked to open a new fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, imagebutton

I am creating an application which consists of a viewpager with different fragments.And these fragments contains different imagebuttons.I want to open fragments when each of these image button is clicked.But i don't know how to do it.I am new to fragments and i don't know much about them.I am trying to make this code since 2 days.Please if you can help me out.So i will be able to complete my project app.
My layout for `NoticeBoard.java` is as below: This contains2 `imagebuttons` and a `listview`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
     xmlns : android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/relative">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#AAAAAA" 

            android:id="@+id/line">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ptu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="#CCCCCC"
                android:clickable="true"
               android:onClick="OnClick"
                android:contentDescription="@string/mko"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="9.9dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img" />



            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ku"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="#CCCCCC"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/mn"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/line"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            >

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

*And my layout for the ptu,cu,ku,htu is same as above but with different adapter set on the above same listview.I have defined different adapters for ptu,hptu,cu and ku in their .java classes*

My `NoticeBoard.java` class is a fragment with the noticeboard layout set as view and a listview.

```
    public class Notice_Board extends Fragment {
         ListView l;
         ImageButton i1,i2,i3,i4;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_noticeboard, container, false);
                l = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nb);
                 String[] title = new String[]{"Important Announcements", "Datesheet", "Results","Placement Drives","Admissions","Entrance exams"};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, title);


                    l.setAdapter(adapter);



                 i1 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ptu);
                                 i2 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.cu);
                    i3 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ku);
                    i4 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.hptu);

                    i1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                              FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                             ft.replace(R.layout.activity_noticeboard,new PTU(),"PTU");


                        }



                    return rootView;



    }   
        }
```

*Below is my `ptu.java` class that contains the same view  and the listview same as noticeboard but setting different values to listview by setting adapter with different values on it.*

```
  public class PTU extends Fragment{

        ListView l;
        ImageButton i2;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_noticeboard, container, false);
        String[] array = new String[] {"Important Announcements", "Results",Programme","Syllabus","Fees","Events","Placement Drives"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);


        l = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nb);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

I want that each time a button is clicked the layout for notice board should appear but with different listview.And i also want when the noticeboard layout opens the ptu imagebutton should appear clicked having the listview in its fragment. 
      Below is my `ku.java` class that contains the same view  and the listview that is for ptu but setting different values to listview by setting adapter with different values on it.

```
    public class KU extends Fragment{

        ListView l;
        ImageButton i2;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_noticeboard, container, false);
        String[] array = new String[] {"Important Announcements", "Results",Programme","Syllabus","Fees","Events","Placement Drives"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);


        l = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nb);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please mension the problems that occured during the app development ?

Comment: yea what is really your issue? fragments do not switch or what?

Comment: Yes i want to switch to different fragments when i click imagebutton in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in your initialisation of fragment manager.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Instead of it, use

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager  = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Here MainActivity is your fragment activity from which you are calling your all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Main fragment manager Activity name fragment activity. this is the main fragment activity manager. you have to set all fragment using by this activity.

```
i1 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ptu);
                                 i2 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.cu);
                    i3 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.ku);
                    i4 = (ImageButton ) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.hptu);

                    i1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {

                          fragmentActiivty.setFragment();
}
```

**Notes:** :SetFragment function is made in fragment-activity class

```
public static void set_view_FAQ() {
        FragmentManager fm = act.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new yourFragnmentName();
        ft.add(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }
```

**Note:** new yourFragmentNAme means yous fragment class likes Ku,ptu,etc

Comment: what is act in void set_view_FAQ()?

Comment: public static SliderActivity act = SliderActivity.this; Because this is static method so that i am use act object as a class current context     Slider activity is your fragmentActivity i use this name